# Is there meanwhile a a2dp out of the box solution for ubunutu server? (pi4)

Tags: server, sound, bluetooth, a2dp

I use ubuntu server for the pi 4 for its 64 bit support. However the repos do not have `bluez-alsa` which is needed for [rpi-audio-receiver](https://github.com/nicokaiser/rpi-audio-receiver).

Are there any other solutions which allow easy a2dp setup?

Comment: Is anybody interested in developing a GPL Docker Image providing a reasonable out-of-the-box UX?